# Why $\det(\mathbf{F}J^{-1/3}) = \det(\mathbf{F})J^{-1}$?

Tags: mathematics, continuum-mechanics

[image]

$J$ is the jacobian, and $F$ is the deformation gradient.

As illustrated in the picture above, I don't understand why is the $\det(J^{-1/3}) = \det(J^{-1})$ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The determinant of any matrix $\mathbf{F}$ multiplied by a scalar $A$ is the determinant of $\mathbf{F}$ times $A^d$, where $d$ is the dimension of the matrix. Here you are concerned with $3 \times 3$ matrices and therefore $d = 3$. In your case $A = J^{-1/3}$, hence $A^3 = J^{-1}$.